# iOS iPad landscape start up orientation issue

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

we have an application which is build in Flex and has only landscape mode build with AIR 14.0 and FB 4.7.

Following settings are set:

landscape

true

Everything works fine except on issue:

When we start the app with the iPad Homebutton on the left the whole application ist rotated upside down. After that we have to rotate the iPad twice to get the application to display correct with the Homebutton left.

Is this a known bug or is there any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto-layout. You can set 'constraints' that help load your imagery in the right spot every time on any device. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isu3xLjjyZg